# What are the steps to make a ModelForm work with a ManyToMany relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, modelform

How to call or implement many to many fields at the template?
the only that i can think of right now is to make another form just specifically for IncomeSection. 
Thus the IncomeSection form will be call again in the view and pass it to the template. 
is there a way that i can put the same form as clientname?

**"updates"**

The real real problem is, i want the form to dynamic so the user can add up salaries and bonuses dynamically (will implement later using javascript). So the db will create new row in IncomeSection table every time user add new salary or bonus.  Therefore, i'm using manaytomany relation with taxcomp table to cater 1 client with many salaries and bonuses situation.. would be glad if anyone can comment on my model and db decision.

**model.py**

```
class Taxcomp(models.Model):
      ClientName = models.CharField(_('Client Name'),max_length=50,blank = True, null= True)
      income = models.ManyToManyField(IncomeSection,blank=True)
class IncomeSection(models.Model):
      Salary= models.CharField(choices=income.choices,max_length=512,null=True,blank=True)
      Bonus= models.CharField(choices=income.choices,max_length=512,null=True,blank=True)
      description = models.CharField(max_length=512,null=True,blank=True)
```

**form.py**

```
class taxCompForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
         model = Taxcomp
         fields = ('__all__')
```

**view.py**

```
def taxcompute(request):
msg = 'Tax Comp Successfully Updated'
msgerror = 'Invalid inputs'
data = request.session.get('session_data')
clientname = data['client_name']

if request.method == "GET":
    form = taxCompForm(initial={'ClientName':clientname})
    formc = ProfileUpdateForm()
    income_list = []
    salary = []
    bonus = []


    taxcompobj = Taxcomp.objects.all()
    header_fields = []

    income_obj = Taxcomp.objects.get(pk=1)
    print(income_obj)

    for income in income_obj.income.all():
        incomeForm = taxCompForm(instance=income)

        if income.title == "Salary":
            salary.append(incomeForm)

        elif income.title == "Bonus":
            bonus.append(incomeForm)
        else:
            comission.append(**incomeForm**)

    salary.append(taxCompForm(initial={'title':'Salary'}))
    bonus.append(taxCompForm(initial={'title':'Bonus'}))
    context ={      
        'form' :form,
        'formc': formc,
        'salaryform': salary,
        'bonusform': bonus  
    }
else:
    form = taxCompForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() :
        form.save()

        messages.success(request, f'{msg}')
        return redirect ('taxcompute')
    else:
        messages.error(request, f'{msgerror}')

        print(inputf.errors)
        return redirect ('taxcompute')


return render (request,'taxcomp.html',context)
```

**taxcomp.html**

```
 {%for bonus in bonusform%}
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <label class="">Bonus</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          {{ bonus.conversion_amount}}
        </div>
      </div>
      {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Have you checked the `ModelMultipleChoiceField`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

Comment: well that's a start. i'll read and try ModelMultipleChoiceField to solve my problem.

Comment: well, from my understanding, ModelMultipleChoiceField leads to my IncomeSection model to part of the choice. i don't want that. i want the IncomeSection to be inputs so that user can later dynamically more salaries and bonuses ( i will implement dynamic input fields in the template). That's why i'm using manytomany relationship. may i should rephrase the question.